# Check whether a web URL is working or not in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to create a selenium script in c# to check whether a URL is working or returning any error. What is the simplest way to do that.

Comment: simply try to find any object like href attribute . You can check this url https://www.swtestacademy.com/verify-url-responses-selenium/

Comment: Using Selenium is useless in that situation, you just have a lot of useless overhead. Use HttpClient as suggested by @Guy

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it with Selenium, use `HttpClient`

```
string url = "url";
var client = new HttpClient();
var checkingResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (checkingResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{url} is alive");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a URL is working or returning any error using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s C# clients, you can simply use  `WebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` class to get the page response and status code as follows:

```
//Declare Webrequest
HttpWebRequest re = null;
re = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)re.GetResponse();
    System.Console.WriteLine($"URL: {url.GetAttribute("href")} status is :{response.StatusCode}");
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
    System.Console.WriteLine($"URL: {url.GetAttribute("href")} status is :{errorResponse.StatusCode}");
}
```